# Create Regular time series from an irregular (as.Date) time series with frequency=23

Tags: datetime, r, time-series, zoo

I have the following problem in R. I would like to create a ts() object (i.e. a regular time series) from a irregular time series (i.e. a list of dates and data values).

You can reproduce the problem with the following data set and R script:

```
# dput(dd) result    
dd <- structure(list(NDVI = structure(c(14L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 20L, 17L, 
    5L, 7L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 19L, 15L, 9L, 3L, 24L, 2L, 6L, 22L, 16L, 
    13L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 1L), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"), .Label = c("0.4186", 
    "0.5452", "0.5915", "0.5956", "0.6010", "0.6860", "0.6966", "0.7159", 
    "0.7161", "0.7264", "0.7281", "0.7523", "0.7542", "0.7701", "0.7751", 
    "0.7810", "0.7933", "0.8075", "0.8113", "0.8148", "0.8207", "0.8302", 
    "0.8305", "0.8369", "0.9877"), class = "factor"), DATUM = structure(c(11005, 
    11021, 11037, 11085, 11101, 11117, 11133, 11149, 11165, 11181, 
    11197, 11213, 11229, 11245, 11261, 11277, 11293, 11309, 11323, 
    11339, 11355, 11371, 11387, 11403, 11419), class = "Date")), .Names = c("NDVI", 
    "DATUM"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"), class = "data.frame")

require(zoo)
dd$DATUM <- as.Date(dd$DATUM,"A%Y%j") # Ayear,julianday
z <- zoo(dd$NDVI,dd$DATUM,frequency=23)
z  # this is a regular time series with a frequency=23 and start=c(2000,1)
# there are 5 measurements in 2000 (2 jan, 1 feb, 2 apr) for which no data is available 
# this should be marked as an NA is the final regular time series
ts.z <- as.ts(z,start=c(2000,1),frequency=23)
```

But this does not work, as I obtain a very long regular time series containing daily time steps.
I would like to obtain a ts object with a frequency=23 correctly indicating the position for which data is not available as NA.

I have been trying everything based on the example listed here for yearly data
[Convert a irregular time series to a regular time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897814/convert-a-irregular-time-series-to-a-regular-time-series)

but it does not work for data with a frequency of 23 (i.e. 23 values a year). I think I could solve it by avoiding to set `dd$DATUM` `as.Date()` but as an zoo object that can be ordered as a time series with 23 values a year.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

23 does not evenly divide into the number of days in a year so you will have to synthesize your own time scale such that each year is divided into 23 equal pieces.  Convert `dd` (the version that has "Date" class times) to zoo and create a new series based on a new scale made up of the year plus a fraction.  Finally convert that to a ts series:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(as.numeric(as.character(dd[[1]])), dd[[2]]) 
lt <- unclass(as.POSIXlt(time(z)))
yr <- lt$year + 1900
jul <- lt$yday
delta <- min(unlist(tapply(jul, yr, diff))) # 16
zz <- aggregate(z, yr + jul / delta / 23)

as.ts(zz)
```

giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2000, 4) 
End = c(2001, 7) 
Frequency = 23 
 [1] 0.7701 0.5956 0.7281     NA     NA 0.7523 0.8148 0.7933 0.6010 0.6966
[11] 0.8207 0.8305 0.9877 0.8113 0.7751 0.7161 0.5915 0.8369 0.5452 0.6860
[21] 0.8302 0.7810 0.7542 0.8075 0.7264 0.7159 0.4186
```

Comment: Yes. This looks great but it is not yet working here since the variable zt is not defined. ps why do you divide by 16? thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jan I'm sure he'll fix it, but my guess is zt<-time(z).   Also, 16*23, which equals 368, appears to be the synthesized time scale for a year.

Comment: @Jan, As Bill pointed out zt is time(z) but I have simplified and cleaned up the code since then which has eliminated it.  The 16 comes from the fact that `diff(time(z))` shows the points are 16 days or multiples of 16 days apart.

Comment: Works great! Beautiful solution. Thanks heaps. The data is actually MODIS satellite data which is summarised (composited) into 16-day time steps. This is a smart solution to create a regular time series (ts class). Cheers

Comment: Have added a calculation which gives `16` so that that value is better justified.